# JVisualVM security consideration

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I want to use JVisualVM, JConsole and JMC not just in testing environments but in Production too, however it looks like I am able to see the values of the specific objects as well as Perform a GC and do a Heap Dump. I am wondering is there a way to restrict the functionality of these utilities to monitoring tasks? Is it possible to deny an access to the object stored on the heap?

Comment: You can restrict the people who can run jvisualvm etc. against your server using 2-way ssl : https://www.lullabot.com/articles/monitor-java-with-jmx